# Using DatePicker control in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to add DatePicker VBA control in an PowerPoint 2007 slide. But I couldn't find any such control.

I have added Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library as well as Microsoft Excel and Powerpoint Object Library, but still I couldn't find any control related to DatePicker.

I'd love if someone can direct me to some article or documentation, tutorial to add it.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Also is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP x86 (32 Bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control isn't included with Office/VBA.  If it's installed on your PC, the answer posted by Jean-François Corbett will get you there, but your code won't work on other PCs unless they also have the needed control installed.

Have a look here:
http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=241456

Comment: What would be the solution to create the application with this control without users requiring to add the references and install the Microsoft control in their system. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: The users don't have to add references; you as the programmer do. But you can't program against a control that isn't there. You'll have to assume that the control's there or ensure it's there by including it in your installation routine; to do that you'd have to be licensed to distribute it.

Comment: Okay, moved from VBA application to .net. Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Developer > Controls > More controls... (the hammer-and-wrench icon) > Microsoft MonthView Control

[image]

Comment: I have tried the more controls list, but the Microsoft Monthview Control 6.0 SP6 is not present in the list. So can you tell me how do I add it to the list. I have tried adding references that I was aware of, but no luck. Can you direct me to exact reference that I need to add. Thanks a lot for the help. :)